# All charts apps need to be terminated before the project can be deleted

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to delete the organization in my MongoDB account but when I try to do that, MongoDB forces me to delete all the projects first. I deleted all my projects except one. When I try to delete this project, a pop up appears like this
[image]

But even if I terminate the cluster and delete the charts, I'm unable to get rid of this pop which is preventing me from deleting the project.
You can see I don't have any charts here
[image]
Nor do I have any clusters

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I got the same issue I deleted the project using these simple step..

- In project dashboard click on three dot icon which is left of delete icon.
- Click on "Visit Project Settings"
- Scroll down to the bottom
- You will see an option "Delete Charts" click on red Delete button
- Come back to project dashboard and now you can delete it without any error